# How to calculate the closest point from my object to a rotating line

Tags: javascript, geometry, 2d, collision-detection

Doing a mini-game like this:

https://bijanmoudi.github.io/teeter-totter/

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bFXp4.png)

My goal is to calculate the offset to the line from my object

I tried to learn how to calculate the collision right but - **unsuccessful**

**Appreciate for your feedback**

Comment: Please, do not post links. Post your code in question.

Comment: I attached the example of the game, I need to understand how they calculate the collision point with getBoundingClientRect(), my code is shitty and so I hope to see a correct way to solve this

Answer (score 0):

you should calculate the distance between object and line like that:

```
const line = document.getElementsById('line')
const obj = document.getElementsById('obj')
const distance = Math.hypot(obj.position.x - line.position.x, obj.position.y - line.position.y);
```

Comment: Tried, that's work if the line is not rotated, but if we rotate that's will work not as expected, it will start to calc the distance to the left top part of the line

Answer (score 0):

When you calculate the distance between a line segment and point, you first need to calculate the nearest point on the infinite line that runs through the segment. Second, you clamp that nearest point to be within the bounds of the line segment. Third, you calculate the distance from the clamped point to your original point.

```
const line = [{x:0,y:0}, {x:10, y:0}]
const point1 = {x:2, y:2}
const point2 = {x:-10, y:2}
const point3 = {x:11, y:-1}

function nearestPointDistance(line, point){

//Get the Ax+By+c = 0 representtion of the line
let vector = {x:line[1].x-line[0].x, y:line[1].y-line[0].y}
lineLength = Math.sqrt(vector.x**2 + vector.y**2)
let normalizedVector = {x:vector.x/lineLength, y:vector.y/lineLength}
let pointVector = {x:point.x - line[0].x,y:point.y - line[0].y}

let dotProduct = vector.x*pointVector.x+vector.y*pointVector.y;
dotProduct /= lineLength

let nearestPoint
if(dotProduct < 0)
    nearestPoint =  line[0];
else if(dotProduct > lineLength)
    nearestPoint =  line[1];
else nearestPoint =  {x:(line[0].x + normalizedVector.x*dotProduct), y:(line[0].y + normalizedVector.y/dotProduct)}

let distance = Math.sqrt((nearestPoint.x - point.x)**2 + (nearestPoint.y - point.y)**2)
return distance;
}

console.log(nearestPoint(line, point1))
console.log(nearestPoint(line, point2))
console.log(nearestPoint(line, point3))
```

Comment: Thanks for answer!
`code
public getDistance(){
const figure = this.figureRef?.current.getBoundingClientRect();
const tetter = this.props.teeterRef.current.getBoundingClientRect();

const lineCoords = [
{
x: tetter.left,
y: tetter.top
},
{
x: tetter.right,
y: tetter.bottom
}
]


return this.nearestPointDistance(lineCoords, {x: figure.left, y: figure.bottom});
}

`
But the problem is the same

Comment: Sorry I don't now how to format code in comments :(